# Могу ли я безопасно использовать CoTaskMemFree вместо IMalloc::Free?

Tags: c++, winapi

Работаю с шеллом, разгребаю старый ленивый код, который вместо плясок с рекомендуемым в PSDK `IMalloc::Free` просто вызывает `CoTaskMemFree`. Собственно вопрос - валиден ли такой подход?

Comment: Ап... и тигры у ног моих встали. Офигеть, [winapi] никто не читает.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По существу - `CoTaskMemAlloc` и `CoTaskMemFree` - это не что иное, как `CoGetMalloc(MEMCTX_TASK) + IMalloc::Alloc()` и `CoGetMalloc(MEMCTX_TASK) + IMalloc::Free()` соответственно.

В связи с этим, ответ на ваш вопрос сильно зависит от того, *с помощью какого аллокатора выделяется память.*

> - Если известно, что операции выделения памяти сделаны с помощью
>   аллокатора, полученного путем вызова
>   `CoGetMalloc(MEMCTX_TASK)`, то
>   `CoTaskMemFree` - это верный подход.
> - Если используется кастомный `IMalloc` *(хотя реализация
>   собственного `COM IMalloc` - это
>   обычно не очень хорошая практика),*
>   то, очевидно, что использовать
>   `CoTaskMemFree` нельзя. В таком случае
>   получится, что вы попросили какой-то
>   **произвольный аллокатор** выделить вам фрагмент памяти, а потом пытаетесь
>   освободить этот же фрагмент, обращаясь
>   к **другому аллокатору.**
> - [**Здесь**](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040705-00/?p=38573) можно посмотреть подробную информацию по поводу использования `CoTaskMemAlloc` и ей подобных функций.

Comment: Собственно, мало что известно, кроме того, что *как-то* распределенный `PIDLIST` рекомендуют особождать шелловским IMalloc (полученным от `SHGetMalloc`)